# Preparing A Grid in Unity (Procedurally)

Tags: unity, procedural

I am trying to create a grid. But the renderer only renders ONE cell of the grid.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cell
{
    public List<Vector3> Vertices;
    public List<int> Triangles;

    public Cell(int x, int y)
    {
        Vertices = new List<Vector3>();
        Triangles = new List<int>();

        Vertices.Add(new Vector3(x - 1, y + 1, 0));
        Vertices.Add(new Vector3(x + 1, y + 1, 0));
        Vertices.Add(new Vector3(x + 1, y - 1, 0));
        Vertices.Add(new Vector3(x - 1, y - 1, 0));

        Triangles.Add(0);
        Triangles.Add(1);
        Triangles.Add(3);
        Triangles.Add(1);
        Triangles.Add(2);
        Triangles.Add(3);
    }
}

public class GridComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int resolution = 8;

    List<Cell> cells = new List<Cell>();

    List<Vector3> gridVertices;
    List<int> gridTriangles;

    Mesh gridMesh;

    void Awake()
    {
        gridMesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        gridVertices = new List<Vector3>();
        gridTriangles = new List<int>();

        for (int x = 0; x < resolution; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < resolution; y++)
            {
                Cell cell = new Cell(x, y);
                cells.Add(cell);
            }
        }

        foreach (Cell cell in cells)
        {
            foreach (Vector3 vertex in cell.Vertices)
            {
                gridVertices.Add(vertex);
            }
            foreach (int triangle in cell.Triangles)
            {
                gridTriangles.Add(triangle);
            }
        }

        gridMesh.vertices = gridVertices.ToArray();
        gridMesh.triangles = gridTriangles.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this doesn't render one cell. Not really at least, it renders the same single identical cell resolution * resolution times.

Let me first say something about the creation of a new Cell object for every cell. You don't need that, it doesn't actually provide anything *good*. It causes a ton of memory allocations that will then all be destroyed, don't do that but instead just write a Cell method that takes the list of vertices, list of triangles and the start coordinates.

But on to why you're rendering one cell, resolution * resolution times. If you enter the debugger and view what your triangles list has at the end of it, you'll see that it's a repetition of "0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3".

Just because you put the indices and vertices in a different object for a moment does not mean that the 0 from `cells[10].triangles[0]` refers to `cells[10].vertices[0]`, it will just refer to `gridVertices[0]`, which happens to be copied from `cells[0]`.

You'll want something like this as a method:

```
public void Cell(int x, int y, List<Vector3> vertices, List<int> triangles)
{
    int indexStart = vertices.Length;

    vertices.Add(new Vector3(x - 1, y + 1, 0));
    vertices.Add(new Vector3(x + 1, y + 1, 0));
    vertices.Add(new Vector3(x + 1, y - 1, 0));
    vertices.Add(new Vector3(x - 1, y - 1, 0));

    triangles.Add(indexStart + 0);
    triangles.Add(indexStart + 1);
    triangles.Add(indexStart + 3);
    triangles.Add(indexStart + 1);
    triangles.Add(indexStart + 2);
    triangles.Add(indexStart + 3);
}
```